# Extra number in the end of a php query

Tags: php, sql

I have the fallowing code in my recupera.inc file:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM info_modulo WHERE id_interacao = 1";
$resultado = mysql_query ($sql);

$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)){

  $array[] = $row;

}

$nome = array_column($array, 'nome');
$imagem = array_column($array, 'imagem');
$comentario = array_column($array, 'comentario');
```

in my index.php file I'm trying to print the result with the fallowing query:

```
<?php 
include "recupera.inc";
echo "<br/>";
echo print_r($nome[0] . " " . $imagem[0] . " " . $comentario[0]) . "</br>";
?>
```

But the problem is that doesn't matter what I try to print, the result always have an "1"in the end, like in this case:

```
test_nome test_imagem teste_comentario1
```

The "1"in "teste_comentario1" doesn't exist in the database

If I try the fallowing:

```
<?php 
include "recupera.inc";
echo "<br/>";
echo print_r($nome[0]) . "</br>";
?>
```

The result is the fallowing:

```
test_nome1
```

Someone knows why it's happening? Thanks a lot!

Comment: why are you doing `echo print_r`?

Comment: stop using `mysql_*`API it is deprecated and removed in the newer php versions. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: you are echoing the return from `print_r`, which is "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two output functions together.

When you do `echo print_r()`, you are telling php to echo whatever `print_r` returns. `print_r` is meant to [echo its output](http://php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php) instead of returning, and it always returns `true` unless it's said otherwise.

So what's happening:

`print_r` prints its output, and returns true. And then `echo` prints the returned `true` (which in string form is 1) from `print_r`, hence your "unexpected" result.

I don't know what are you trying to accomplish with your `print_r` there, but just remove it and your code should work properly.

Completely unrelated to your problem, but as one of the comments said, you should be using the `mysqli_` family of functions. The `myslq_` family has been deprecated for some time now.

Comment: I also changed to mysqli_ as you guys said, thanks for that tip too
(I had to wait some minutes before could accept the answer :P)